# Issue testing with ask future in akka with scalatest

Tags: scala, akka, scalatest

I am trying to run a simple actor test which should print test on request. The future is not being finished.

```
package test

import akka.actor.Actor.Receive
import akka.actor.{Actor, ActorSystem}
import akka.testkit.{TestActorRef, TestProbe, ImplicitSender, TestKit}
import akka.util.Timeout
import org.scalatest.{BeforeAndAfterAll, BeforeAndAfterEach, Matchers, WordSpecLike}

class TestSpecs(_system:ActorSystem)
  extends TestKit(_system)
  with ImplicitSender
  with WordSpecLike
  with Matchers {
  def this() = this(ActorSystem("test"))

  class TestTestTest extends Actor {
    override def receive: Receive = {
      case "test" =>  "test"
      case _ => "notest"
    }
  }

    val workerFSM = TestActorRef(new TestTestTest)

  "During initialization connection should" should {
    "have initial state as pre initialization" in {
        import scala.concurrent.duration.DurationInt
        implicit val timeout = Timeout(5.seconds)
        import akka.pattern.ask
        import system.dispatcher
        val f = workerFSM ? "test"
        println(f.isCompleted)
        f.map(x => {
          println("Hello")
        })
        expectMsg(2.seconds, "test")

    }
  }
}
```

Is it issue with blocking nature of future in akka tests or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you "ask" an actor something, that actor must reply or the future returned to the original caller will never complete.  In your case, `TestTestTest` never replies, so your future `f` in your test will never complete.